# Serial data over UDP Sockets in Python

Tags: python, serial-port, udp

I may be going about this the wrong way but that's why I'm asking the question.

I have a source of serial data that is connected to a SOC then streams the serial data up to a socket on my server over UDP. The baud rate of the raw data is 57600, I'm trying to use Python to receive and parse the data. I tested that I'm receiving the data successfully on the port via the script below (found here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication)

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "MY IP"
UDP_PORT = My PORT

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
   print "received message:", data
```

Since I'm not reading the data with the .serial lib in Python or setting the baud rate to read at it comes all garbled, as would be expected. My end goal is to be able to receive and parse the data for server side processing and also have another client connect to the raw data stream piped back out from the server (proxy) which is why I'm not processing the data directly from the serial port on the device.

So my question is, how can I have Python treat the socket as a serial port that I can set a baud rate on and #import serial and .read from? I can't seem to find any examples online which makes me think I'm overlooking something simple or am trying to do something stupid.

## sadface

Answer (score 1):

You can't treat a socket as a serial line. A socket can only send and receive data (data stream for TCP, packets for UDP). If you would need a facility to control the serial line on the SOC you would need to build an appropriate control protocol over the socket, i.e. either use another socket for control like FTP does or use in-band control and distinguish between controlling and data like HTTP does. And of course both sides of the connection have to understand this protocol.

Comment: In that case would you recommend I stream the serial data that will then proxy and also try and parse and then send what I'll need to use on the server from the SOC? Sending the same data twice does not seem like an adequate solution. The recipient client of the serial data (i did not write it) requires/understands the UDP stream at 57600.

Comment: I think you have to distinguish between controlling the serial line or receiving the data only. For the first look at things like virtual COM ports, serial over TCP or UDP... - which sometimes use different ports for data and control. If you just want receive the data you need to setup the SOC once to 57600 and then just read the data, i.e. there would be nothing specific to serial lines in the receiver. "The recipient...requires/understands the UDP stream at 57600" - does this just mean that it expects a specific amount of data per time or is there more to this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

### Build on facts

A first thing to start with is to summarise facts -- **begining from the very SystemOnChip** (SOC) all the way up ...:

1. an originator serial-bitstream parameters ::= **57600** Bd, **X**-<*dataBIT*>-s, **Y**-<*stopBIT*>, **Z**-<*parityBIT*>,
2. a mediator receiving process de-framing <*data*> from a raw-bitstream
3. a mediator upStream sending to server-process integration needs specification ( FSA-model of a multi-party hand-shaking, fault-detection, failure-state-resilience, logging, ... )
4. T.B.C. ...

### Design as per a valid requirement list

A few things work as a just bunch of SLOC one-liners. Design carefully against the validated Requirement List as a principle. It saves both your side and the cooperating Team(s).

### Test on models

Worth a time to test on-the-fly, during the efforts to progress from simple parts to more complex, multiparty scenarios.

### Integrate on smarter frameworks

Definitely a waste of time to reinvent wheel. Using a smart framework for server-side integration will unlock a lot of your time and energy on your ProblemDOMAIN-specific tasks, rather than to waste both the former and the latter for writing your just-another-socket-framework ( destined in majority of cases to failure ... )

Try **ZeroMQ** or a **nanomsg** Scale-able Formal Communication Patterns Framework for smart-services to send de-framed data from your serial-bitStream source and you are almost there.